# JS Sorting superior array of objects depending on object value using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have the following structure:

```
let drives = [
    {id: 1, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 1},
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2}]
    },
    {id: 2, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: -2}]
    },
    {id: 3, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 5}, 
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2}, 
        {moveId: 3, difference: 4}]
    },
    {id: 4, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 6}]
    }
]
```

Now I want to sort the drives array by the move's difference.The result should be something like this (depending on sort order).

```
let drives = [
    {id: 2, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: -2}]
    },
    {id: 1, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 1},
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2}]
    },
    {id: 3, moves:[
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2},
        {moveId: 3, difference: 4},
        {moveId: 1, difference: 5}]
    },
    {id: 4, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 6}]
    }
]
```

I tried to do this with lodash using this code

```
_.orderBy(drives, 'moves.difference', 'asc');
```

But this seems to do nothing. 
Has anyone an idea how to handle this?

Comment: Hmm..Do you mean by sum of the differences for every driver ?

Comment: Not the sum of the move's differences. At first, the moves array of each drives object should be sorted by their difference (or any other key). After that, the drives array should be sorted by the the move's differences. - I edited my post, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @michaelT: Please have a look at my solution for your first part. As for the second part, I've raised a case, please help to answer in order to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested approach by sorting the inner `moves` and then the outer move by taking the first element for sorting.

```js
var drives = drives = [{ id: 1, moves: [{ moveId: 1, difference: 1 }, { moveId: 2, difference: 2 }] }, { id: 2, moves: [{ moveId: 1, difference: -2 }] }, { id: 3, moves: [{ moveId: 1, difference: 5 }, { moveId: 2, difference: 2 }, { moveId: 3, difference: 4 }] }, { id: 4, moves: [{ moveId: 1, difference: 6 }] }];

console.log(
    _(drives)
         .map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { moves: _.sortBy(o.moves, 'difference') }))
         .sortBy(({ moves: [{ difference }] }) => difference)
         .value()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just tried it, works as I want it! Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to have to tackle for two parts. For first part sort their own array first so the answer would be as below

```js
let drives = [
      {id: 1, moves:[
               {moveId: 1, difference: 1},
               {moveId: 2, difference: 2}]
      },
      {id: 2, moves:[
               {moveId: 1, difference: -2}]
      },
      {id: 3, moves:[
               {moveId: 1, difference: 5}, 
               {moveId: 2, difference: 2}, 
               {moveId: 3, difference: 4}]
      }
    ]

    drives.forEach(x=> {
     x.moves.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.difference - b.difference;
      });
    });

    drives.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.moves[0].difference - b.moves[0].difference;
    });
    
    console.log(drives);
```

As for the second part, I'm not sure what's your condition to swap between id 2 and id 1.

```
let drives = [
  {id: 1, moves:[
       {moveId: 1, difference: 1},
       {moveId: 2, difference: 2}]
  },
  {id: 2, moves:[
       {moveId: 1, difference: -2},
       {moveId: 2, difference: 4}]
  }]
```

If for above cases, will `id:2` comes first or remain same sequence?

Comment: id 1 comes first, then id 2 because id 1 has a move with a smallest difference of -3 and id 2 is -2 (if I use ascending order). When there are two drive objects with the same smallest move's difference, the sequence of the both objects does not matter.

Comment: Do have a look at the solution.It's essentially the same idea as @Hassan's answer just syntax differences

Comment: Your solution also works fine. Thank you! But I've one question: If I want to use a function to sort the drives array with a dynamic sort key like function sortDirves(sortKey) -  because I have more than the difference key in the move's object. How can I insert the dynamic sort Key in your code? Just using a.moves[0][sortKey] instead of a.moves[0].difference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort twice. First, sort the `moves` array. Once all the `moves` array is sorted. Then sort based on the `difference` value at the first index.

```js
let drives = [ {id: 1, moves:[ {moveId: 1, difference: 1}, {moveId: 2, difference: 2}] }, {id: 2, moves:[ {moveId: 1, difference: -2}] }, {id: 3, moves:[ {moveId: 1, difference: 5}, {moveId: 2, difference: 2}, {moveId: 3, difference: 4}] }, {id: 4, moves:[{moveId: 1, difference: 6}] } ];
drives.forEach(o => o.moves.sort((a,b) => a.difference - b.difference));
drives.sort((a,b) => a.moves[0].difference - b.moves[0].difference);
console.log(drives);
```

Comment: Your solution for second sorting is based on solely first item? Can you have a look at the case I've raised? What do you think the OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation has 2 solutions the way I see it.
In order to get to the solution you need you need decide the method by which you want to rank your drives. Unfortunately your method could lead to unexpected results in the future.

You will find that there will be duplicate difference values across moves and given this situation you need to decide which of the drives will have more weight in the sorting algorithm.

Below you can find a rankMap object being built with the biggest and smallest difference across drives to later help you sort your array.

Hope this helps

```
    let drives = [
    {id: 1, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 1},
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2}]
    },
    {id: 2, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: -2}]
    },
    {id: 3, moves:[
        {moveId: 1, difference: 5}, 
        {moveId: 2, difference: 2}, 
        {moveId: 3, difference: 4}]
    }
];

// we build a rankMap by which we will later sort the array of objects
let rankMap = {};

drives = drives.map(drive => {
    let
        biggestDiff = null,
        smallestDiff = null;

    let moves = _.orderBy(drive.moves, move => {
        if(biggestDiff < move.difference || biggestDiff === null) {
            biggestDiff = move.difference;
        }
        if(smallestDiff > move.difference || smallestDiff === null) {
            smallestDiff = move.difference;
        }

        return move.difference;
    }, ['asc']);

    rankMap[drive.id] = {
        smallestDiff: smallestDiff,
        biggestDiff: biggestDiff
    };

    return Object.assign({}, drive, {
        moves: moves
    });
});

let
    sortedByBiggestDifference = _.orderBy(drives, drive => rankMap[drive.id].biggestDiff, ['asc']),
    sortedBySmallestDifference = _.orderBy(drives, drive => rankMap[drive.id].smallestDiff, ['asc']);

console.log(drives);
console.log(sortedByBiggestDifference);
console.log(sortedBySmallestDifference);
```